# How to split parameter value passed in with two values?

Tags: javascript

I have this JS:

```
function SetAPIValue(key1, value1, scormVersion, methodCalled) {
   if (key1 == true || key1 == false) { }
   else
   {
     alert("value1 = " + value1);
     /* value1 came back with two values for cmi.suspend_data! */
     var obj = {
       key: key1,
       value: value1
    }
   setValuesArray.push(obj);
 }
```

somehow or another value1 contains two values for key1, how can I spit them when I push to my array so each value and key is in a row?

thanks

Comment: That depends... is `value1` an object, an array, a delimited string, or something else? Can you provide the actual value of `value1` in your question?

Comment: That depends on what `value1` *is*.  How does it contain two values - is it a string with the two values concatenated?  Is it an array of two elements?  Is it an object with `firstValue` and `secondValue` properties?  Is it something else?

Comment: it is an array with 2 values: Varch02_complete=1;Varch01_complete=1 ,exactly like this in the alert i have there

Comment: @charlie_cat that doesn't immediately look like an array to me (I wouldn't expect it to include property names).  Are you sure it's an array of two strings: `["Varch02_complete=1", "Varch01_complete=1"]`, or might it be something else?

Comment: in the alert the popup displays the value1 as: Varch02_complete=1;Varch01_complete=1 exactly no quotes only ";" inbetween and at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `value1` is an array containing multiple values:

```
function SetAPIValue(key1, value1, scormVersion, methodCalled) {
    if (value1 instanceof Array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < value1.length; i++) {
            setValuesArray.push({
                key: key1,
                value: value1[i]
            );
        }
    } else {
        setValuesArray.push({
            key: key1,
            value: value1
        });
    }
 }
```

Note this will leave you with multiple objects with the same key, which may not be desirable.